# JS - Regex for name

Tags: javascript, regex

- The username should contain only alphabatic chars (a-z) up to 25 chars.
- The first and the last space should be removed.
- The username can be more then 1 word, not a limit for how many words the name counts

So the regex I am using now is almost valid, except that a username with 3 words or more isn't valid. And this should be valid.

Valid names can be:

1. Dennis
2. Dennis is
3. Dennis is cool
4. Dennis is the coolest
5. etc.. up to 25 chars because this is the max length.

This is the current regex I am using:

```
    var pattern = /^[a-z\u00C0-\u01FF]+([\s\.\-\']?[a-z\u00C0-\u01FF]+)? $/i;
    if (pattern.exec(uname) == null)
    {
       alert('Invalid name');
       return false;
    }
```

So how to adjust the regex to make it work for more words then 2 with a maximum length of 25 chars?

Comment: If it only can be alphabetic characters and spaces, why do you have this: `[\s\.\-\']`?

Comment: This is what I would use: `^\s*((?:[a-z ]){1,25}?)\s*$`

Comment: Sorry my mistake. And your solution is fine except a name with only spaces is allowed, which shouldn't

Comment: `^\s*([a-z](?:[a-z ]){0,24}?)\s*$`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex specifies it requires one set of characters, then optionally, a space and another set of characters. Hence your two word limit.

If you changed `([\s\.\-\']?[a-z\u00C0-\u01FF]+)?` to `([\s\.\-\']?[a-z\u00C0-\u01FF]+)*`, it would allow zero or more additional words, rather than zero or one.